# Bootstrap card class not working properly on angular 2

Tags: angular

Bootstrap card class not working properly on angular 2 while running the below code, only the texts to be displayed.

```
<div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-6">
  <div class="card card-primary card-inverse">
    <div class="card-header card-primary">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
          <i class="fa fa-comments fa-5x"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9 text-xs-right">
          <div class="huge">26</div>
          <div>New Comments!</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Dis you include bootstrap css in your index.html ?

Comment: yes, i added them and some bootstrap staff are working ok.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you have any solution for that